# Static ip address on Windows Azure for GestPay e-commerce website

Tags: azure, cloud, static-ip-address

Is possible to have a static ip address for a VM on Windows Azure? i need to integrate GestPay for online payment in asp.net mvc5 e-commerce application. 
Thank you﻿

Answer (score 1):

1. If you're using Azure Cloud Service - you need to create production deployment and deploy your package. After this - you'll get dedicated IP-Address. Then for redeploy you'll have to use Azure Swap strategy, deploying through staging and performing Swap. All the other ways like recreating production deployment etc. - will change IP Address.
2. If you're using Azure VM - static IP addresses within Virtual Network appeared recently for them. You can find more here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/matthewms/archive/2014/03/07/setting-static-ip-address-in-windows-azure-virtual-machines.aspx